# Runtime exec pauses half way through execution

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I'm running a Java (.jar) program from a bat script that near the end has the following (on windows)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svn co http://myrepository.com/someproj");
Thread.sleep(20000);
```

It checks out about 1/10th of the directories and 1 file and then it does nothing.  I suspect the reason it is pausing on the file but I couldn't find anything. The bat script is run as an administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common reason for an `exec` command to block is that it is either waiting for input from the parent process (or the console), or blocked because the parent process is not reading the child processes standard output or error stream.